# Remove all switched dictionary pairs

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` and want to `LINQ`-remove all pairs (B, A) if there is a pair (A, B).

```
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dictionary.Add(1, 2);
dictionary.Add(3, 4); // keep it
dictionary.Add(4, 3); // remove it
//dictionary.Add(4, 3); // remove it (ignore this impossible line, @Rahul Singh is right)
```

Comment: You can't add an item in dictionary with Key `4` again! And BTW you know what (A,B) is how program will understand what is A? It can be (4,3) as well right?

Comment: Advise caution here since dictionaries do not necessarily preserve insertion order. If you add (4,3) before adding (3,4), would you expect a different output?

Comment: @Softerware: No, no problem, order does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom equality comparer and use the Distinct method.

```
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dictionary.Add(1, 2);
 dictionary.Add(3, 4);
dictionary.Add(4, 3);

var result = dictionary.Distinct(new KeyValuePairEqualityComparer()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    }
```

The equality comparer is defined as

```
private class KeyValuePairEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<int, int> x, KeyValuePair<int, int> y)
    {
        return x.Key == y.Value && x.Value == y.Key;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<int, int> obj)
    {
        // Equality check happens on HashCodes first.
        // Multiplying key/value pairs, ensures that mirrors
        // are forced to check for equality via the Equals method
        return obj.Key * obj.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I've updated the answer. My own test (using your supplied values) now returns the desired result.

Comment: Ah yes. It has to be public if it isn't a class nested within the class wherein it is used. Glad to hear you got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be to simply filter them as you need.

```
dictionary = dictionary
.Where( kvp => !(dictionary.ContainsKey(kvp.Value) && dictionary[kvp.Value]==kvp.Key) )
.ToDictionary( kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value )`
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your pair is `(1,2)`, for removing this pair from the dictionary you need not to bother about the value, Since Keys are unique. So you can delete using the following code:`dictionary.Remove(pair.Key);`

But there is a chance for `KeyNotFoundException` if the specified key is not found in the collection. so its always better to check for that before proceeding with remove:

```
int value;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value))
{
   dictionary.Remove(pair.Key);
}
```